# Page displays fine in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer but all the content is pushed off in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, formatting

I'm developing this site here for a client of mine:  http://test.bebiafricanhairbraiding.com/osa/index.html

I've encountered a problem that I've never really had before, IE works fine with it, as well as Google Chrome; however, Mozilla Firefox shoves all the content on the front page to the far right - off of the main page.

I can't really provide any code because I can't really determine where the problem lies, however, feel free to inspect source and snoop around a bit.  I just can't figure out why Mozilla just now got the audacity to throw my main page out the window...

Thanks if you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is being floated off your page, just add `clear:both` to it and it will place itself correctly.

```
<div id="cnbo">
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Body" -->
<table style="width: 100%; clear: both;"> /* here */
....
```

Comment: @DadeLamkins your elements are not being properly resetted is all so your table was being calculated as a new block-level element and being pushed to the side instead of being nested, you can test that out by adding something like `* { margin:0; padding:0; }` to your stylesheet but i suggest you add a proper [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) sheet as they fix many of this kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1):

@Andres llich is correct. But I would put it in the CSS itself and not as a style in the table.

```
#cnbo {
font-family: "Arial",Times,serif;
margin-top: 2px;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
word-wrap: break-word;
clear: both;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, this project has gotten a little bit messy (multiple people have been working on it during different time frames).  I'll make sure to stick it in the style for yeah ;)